# How does a POST request to a staging site work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, unit-testing, graphql

I'm working on an app written in Ruby on Rails with GraphQL API. In my test file, I sent a POST request to our staging site in order to execute a sign in mutation. This is the test file:

```
require 'test_helper'

class Mutations::SignInUserTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
    def perform(args = {})
        Mutations::SignInUser.new(object: nil, field: nil, context: {}).resolve(args)
    end

    test 'sign in user' do
        post "apistaging.app.com/graphql"

        user = perform(
            auth: {
                user_id: "example",
                password: "example"
            }
        )

        assert user.persisted?
    end
end
```

However, in `test.log`, this is what I see when I run `rails test`

```
Started POST "/graphql" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-06-16 00:06:27 +0700
Processing by GraphqlController#execute as HTML
Completed 200 OK in 32ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Note that I have a Dockerfile and a docker-compose.yml in my root directory, ran `docker-compose up` then `docker exec` into the container of our app to run `rails test`. Does the log mean that the POST request is being sent to my localhost:3000/graphql? I'm asking because the staging database should have user data for signing in, but for some reason the database is empty when I run the tests, so all the queries and mutations return null.
I also have a .sql file in my root directory, is there a way to import the data in the file into my database so I can test it?

Answer (score 0):

First thing i think you missed is `docker-compose build`. After that you should `docker-compose up`. Also you have to know what port your docker is configured to. The default value is 80, however your port may already be in use and it is not good practice to leave the docker port to 80. What you should do in your `Dockerfile` is:

```
EXPOSE 5050 #or any other port you want
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

`EXPOSE 5050` exposes the port 5050 on your local machine for the docker to use
`CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]` lets you use any ip address in its network and you dont have to worry about managing the ip address

and in your `docker-compose.yml`:

```
your-api:
    ports:
      - 5050:5050
```

So when `docker-compose build` runs it will compose your docker and open the port 5050 for it to use so then you can access `localhost:5050` and have access to your dockerised api and endpoints.

That way you will know for sure your POST request is sent to the docker api when you `POST localhost:5050/graphql`

[Please have a look at the docker for rails documentation, it will be helpfull](https://docs.docker.com/samples/rails/)